# Find and remove the source of a 'using' in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, using

How does one find where a 'using' comes from (which file?) I have removed all related files so Visual Studio 2017 should tell me it can't find the .dll but for an unknown reason it's saying it can find it no problem.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "where a using comes from"? A using directive imports a *namespace* (usually) - not an assembly. So if there are any other assemblies that contain accessible types in the imported namespace, removing a different assembly wouldn't make any difference.

Comment: These kinds of activities should be always followed by a Clean Solution, Rebuild Solution.

Comment: @Steve I have done that multiple times. Sadly doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Since searching for it doesn't work, can you tell us what the namespace is? Is it your own code?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Object Browser:

1. Open the Object Browser (View| Object Browser).
2. Locate the namespace mentioned by the `using` statement.
3. Track it back up to the assembly in the object browser.
4. The bottom-right corner of the Object Browser will tell you the assembly location/filename. If it's a namespace in your own project, you can navigate into the namespace using the tree view, right-click a type in that namespace and select "Go to definition".

To expand on 4 -

If it's an external library, you can see the file location by clicking on the assembly in the treeview:

[image]

If it's your a namespace provided by one of your own projects, you can navigate to the namespace in the treeview, select a Type in that namespace and click "Go to definition":

[image]

Comment: It's "View | Object Browser" (not Edit)... at least in VS15 which I'm using (your mileage may vary)

Comment: @freefaller Thanks. My mistake :)

Comment: Sadly searching for the name of the using directive doesn't return any results.